# centering an element using html-css

Tags: html, css

My html page is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello there</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
Hello world
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My css file is:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#content{
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

But the content div is not centered properly.
I am using IE7 to view this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `<!doctype>` to the beginning of your document, also remove the `display: block;` from your div selector, a div is by default a block level element so this declaration has no meaning. (this won't break the layout, it just makes no sense to tell an already block level element to be block again.)

Other than that, your CSS is perfectly fine :)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello there</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
Hello world
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#content{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5w8F/

Answer (score -1):

For IE 7 quirksmode (and IE 6) you can add

```
html, body{
    text-align: center;
}
div#content{
    text-align: left;
}
```

to center the div... (old skool)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't do anything at all to center anything but text: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/kM394/

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks in addition to the question's CSS it does in fact center the div...open this in IE 7 quirks http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/6SJcf/1/

Comment: Aha, in _addition_ to the CSS. Should specify that a bit clearer in the answer.

Comment: `you can add` *is* in the answer